# How to write to a file synchronously after fork()?

Tags: c, file, asynchronous, network-programming

I am going to implement a server in C as a course project. The server should serve more than one client simultaneously. Description of the project states that fork() should be used to serve more than one client. Each children should write something to a common file. How to handle this synchronously? Is there any mechanism like in Java where only one thread can use a  function at the same time?

Comment: the file system will handle the "only one write at a time" issue; don't overthink this

Comment: Anyway, you can implement a custom file structure, in whihch you use a pthread_lock to, well, lock the simoultaneous I/O actions.

Comment: @H2CO3 that is overkill; standard use of a lock file achieves the same without the crazy

Comment: @tbert is it ok to use fopen in each thread for writing?

Comment: @fenerfan18 yes; depending on the exact semantics you want to happen, you'll have to get the args right to the fopen call (e.g., append, overwrite, etc), but only one write will happen at a time, period, unless there's a bug in your OS ETA: there's no guarantee of child write order, I should add, so don't be surprised if they write out of order

Comment: @H2CO3 fork() starts a new process, not a new thread. The solution to the problem does not lie in thread primitives.

Comment: @EJP I can't find a comment that I wrote and it states that fork() creates a new thread (I did not even mention fork, did I?)

Comment: @H2CO3 Your comment says to use `pthread_lock()`. That provides locks across threads. There are no threads here, only processes, the ones that `fork()` creates. What the OP needs is a file lock.

Comment: im curious why ur allowing multi processes writing one same file lol.i guess u could use pthread_mutex() or pthread_lock()...but mutex is not pretty here cuz u might come across a file locked by multi locks...oh i guess could also have a threadpool-like mechanism,basically u schedule processes with sort of rule or sth...